# Regex code for ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, regex

I am new to regular expression

I am trying to write a regular expression for my ruby code that detect double inverted commas between double inverted commas.

I have this Regular expression that runs fine in ruby 1.9.3

```
 /(?<!^|,)"(?!,|$)/
```

for this string of array.

s = ( "name: ","1234 ",,,*"S.M. red "B" Tease "*)

the italic s[4] which has double inverted comma inside double inverted commas.

In ruby 1.9.3 the above written regular expression detect s[4] i.e ("B")

I tried to write this regular expression for ruby 1.8.7 it gives error

```
 Undefined (?...) sequence. You might be trying to use named groups with Ruby 1.8.7.
```

Thanks a lot if you help me to write this Regular expression code for ruby 1.8.7

I want this string of array as

s = ( "name: ","1234 ",,,*"S.M. red B Tease "*)

so that i can easily import it to my program as a .csv file.

Comment: Could you explain what you expect your original regex to do ?

Comment: When I try your regex in 1.9.3 on your sample data, it does not match `B`, but matches the quote character `"` just before it. Could you add Ruby code that gets you the `B` (assuming that is your goal here).

Comment: To substitute the double inverted commas with space inside double inverted commas. i have to import this string inside csv file but if this type("...".."...."  here (...) means some text of anything) of sequence exists then it can't be exported. from this string "S.M. red "B" Tease " I want to replace "B" with space.

Comment: @Neil Slater sorry it will matches " ".

Comment: Answer please i stuck with this code...no one good in regex on stack.!!

Comment: @DeepakKumarJha No one is good Deepak ! Let's hope MacGyver  is around !

Comment: @oldergod then answer sir..

Comment: @sawa, oldergod, bensiu, Anand, cale_b  . I edited this question. if anything more i need to add please inform me to add. thanks for your positive feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby 1.8.7 doesn't have lookbehind; that's why it fails for you. So I came up with this hack. It has the advantage of preserving the text that's inside the unwanted " characters.

```
'"ab","c"d"e",,,"f"'.gsub(/(^\")|(\",+\")|(\"$)/) {|s|s.gsub('"','#')}.gsub('"',"'").gsub('#','"')
=> "\"ab\",\"c'd'e\",,,\"f\""
```

What I'm doing here is to substitute all " at the start or end, or with only commas between, with a # character; then substitute all remaining " with ' characters; then substitute the # back to " characters. Instead of # you can use any character or string that you know will not be present in your file.

Comment: A solid answer IMO. The OP may also have a non-code solution - contacting source of non-valid CSV and asking them to fix it (non-valid data formats probably cost both parties extra work for no good reason), but that isn't something SO can really advise on.